# JavaScript Date converted to UTC on HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, highcharts

I am parsing CSV data for placement on a HighCharts chart. My date field is located in the first column like this:

```
Time, Summary
9/1/2015 12:00 AM,189
9/1/2015 12:15 AM,202
```

For parsing the data, I use this:

```
var dataSeries = []
    var lines = csv.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');
        if (lineNo !== 0) {
            var x = +new Date(items[0]),
                summary = parseInt(items[1]);
            dataSeries.push([x, summary]);
        }
    });
```

When the data gets placed on my chart, it seems to be UTC time rather than the actual time specified in the CSV data. My chart starts at 5:00 AM rather than 12:00 AM. I setup my chart like this:

```
 var options = { 
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
            renderTo: 'chart1'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Hour'
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%b %e %l:%M %P',
                hour: '%l:%M %P'
            },                    
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Average Whatever'
            },
            min: 0,
        },{opposite: true, min: 1}],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    chart.addSeries({
        name: 'Summaries',       
        data: dataSeries,
        type: 'line',
        marker: { enabled: true }
    });
});
```

Here is a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txouunvx/).

Comment: try adding `pointstart: [value to start at]` to your series

edit: actually, probably  in your xAxis, after your formats add the pointstart

Comment: maybe add `useUTC: False` to your options

Comment: Neither of those seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

use below function before your highchart invocation . Its will prevent date to shown as utc dates.

```
$( function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions( {
        lang : {
            rangeSelectorZoom : ' '
        },
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, simple demo

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 8, 1,12,0),
                pointInterval:  3600 * 1000 // one hour
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddx0upcd/

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time 

Demo for use with irregular time intervals